# BulkExecotor threw Microsoft.Azure.Documents.InvalidPartitionException

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

When the CosmosDb partition auto-scales (transparently), the BulkExecutor starts failing with Microsoft.Azure.Documents.InvalidPartitionException (stack trace below).

This exception cannot be caught easily since the exception class is declared library internal and not a public class.

Question:

1. What is the correct way to handle bulk ingestion when the service transparently auto-scales. Is the Bulk-Executor library expected to refresh the partition map, and retry on it's own, or does the caller need to handle this scenario (and potentially other scenarios).
2. What is the correct way to catch specific CosmosDb exceptions without resorting to catching all exceptions including other System exceptions?

`Microsoft.Azure.Documents.InvalidPartitionException:
   at Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.CongestionController+<>c__DisplayClass17_0+<<ExecuteAllAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport, Version=1.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.CongestionController+<ExecuteAllAsync>d__17.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport, Version=1.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.BulkExecutor+<ExecuteBulkImportImplAsync>d__19.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkImport, Version=1.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. I'd add a git hub issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started/issues

Answer (score 0):

A workaround until they publicly expose this exception is to look at the type name:

```
catch (Exception exception) when (exception.GetType().Name == "InvalidPartitionException")
```